# How to setup autostart of monerod in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: monerod, linux

I've setup the systemd service:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/monerod.service 
[Unit]
Description=Starts Monero Node

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
After=networking.service
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/monero-v0.10.3.1/monerod --config-file /etc/bitmonero.conf
```

But it fails to start with:

```
Jul 10 18:19:09 uminer systemd[1]: monerod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 10 18:19:09 uminer systemd[1]: monerod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 10 18:19:09 uminer systemd[1]: monerod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

UPD: I also tried '--non-interactive' option, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the dev's conf there was mentioned that the 'GuessMainPID=no' of the service file is necessary. The sample service file is [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/utils/systemd/monerod.service).

Comment: +1 for linkning the originalk source sample but i had better luck with the service from this link https://getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/cli_wallet_daemon_isolation_qubes_whonix.html